# in azure ml, git statement in docker conda_file not executing

Tags: azure, docker, pip, conda

I am setting up to deploy Azure ml. The model pickle file is generated.

```
image_config = ContainerImage.image_configuration(runtime= "python",
                                 execution_script="score.py",
                                 conda_file="models/myenv.yml",
                                 docker_file="Dockerfile.steps",
                                 tags = {'label': "duration", 'type': "classification"},
                                 description = "Image duration classification model")
```

in myenv.yml, one of my packages is not a published lib in conda repo. The installation instruction is to do

```
pip install git+https://github.com/MaxHalford/xam --upgrade
```

after looking up some instructions, I believe the right way to set it up in the yml files is

```
- pip:
  - azureml-defaults==1.0.57.*
  - git+https://github.com/MaxHalford/xam --upgrade
```

the docker image builds fine, but when building a container, it crashes and complains

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xam'
```

There are no indication in the messages that it attempted or had trouble with running the git+http line under pip.

Does any one see anything I did wrong and How do I debug this further?